# Обновить jTableModel при изменениях в колекции

Tags: java

есть коллекция с данными

```
static ArrayList<MyBeans> all = new ArrayList<MyBeans>();
```

есть таблица, что выводит ее на экран

```
TableModel model = new Table(all);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

допустим `ArrayList<MyBeans> all` динамически изменился.
Как передать эти изменения в таблицу ??

Answer (score 1):

У модели есть метод fireTableDataChanged() или около того. Изменил - вызови и таблица отразит изменения

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.